# Horror movie set in an arctic research station

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Set in the arctic / Antarctic with several different huts and a team of scientists. Slowly they get struck down by a mystery virus which turns them into monsters who's tongues shoot out even when their heads are cut off. This enables them to drag them across the floor.  I saw this on TV about 25 years ago and would love to know what its called please.

Comment: Do you mean the horror classic *The Thing*?

Comment: Thanks Will / Walt, that's exactly the movie. Watching that clip on YouTube was still as scary today as it was back then. Now all I need to do is tell my son about it !   Thanks again.

Answer (score 28):

That sounds like John Carpenter's remake of [The Thing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/), (1982).

> Scientists in the Antarctic are confronted by a shape-shifting alien
>   that assumes the appearance of the people that it kills.

There is a scene like you describe, with a severed head pulling itself along the floor with a long prehensile tongue.  You can watch that clip [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjIXwkX1e48#t=63).

Comment: Greatest movie clip ever.